# Google Sheets - Counting a range for containing strings

Tags: google-sheets

I've made a google form that automatically goes onto a google spreadsheet, but I have an issue.

When it saves the multiple choice questions, the answers are saved as one string with commas in-between `(E.G. "Answer1, Answer2")`

I need to take a sum of each answer in a range, but functions like `=FIND()` don't search ranges. I've looked on the function list for a little while now, and can't find the answer. Any solution would help.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data and your _hand-entered_ expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, including:

`=countif('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, "*Answer1*")`

or

`=counta( iferror( filter( 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B, search("Answer1", 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B) ) ) )`

or

`=query('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, "select count(B) where B contains 'Answer1' ", 0 )`